# Mock method call in import call

Tags: python, unit-testing, keras, mocking

I’m writing unit test for class what uses Keras lib. My class looks like this:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.model = Sequential()
        …

    def save(self):
        …
        model_json = self.model.to_json()
        json_file.write(model_json)
        ...
```

Because importing Keras takes like 3 seconds in my unit test class I'm mocking them like that:

```
sys.modules['keras'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['keras.models'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['keras.layers'] = MagicMock()
```

When I’m running test for `save` function I get error that `model_json` is a `MagicMock` object not a `str`. And in fact `self.model.to_json()` returns a MagicMock object. I tried many different things to make `self.model.to_json()` return my string but so far nothing worked. How can I `make to_json()` function in `MyClass` return a string defined by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to patch the function?

```
import json
class MyClass:

    def to_json():
        return json.dumps({'to_json': 'default'})

my_class = MyClass()

my_class.to_json = lambda: json.dumps({'hello': 'world'})

print(my_class.to_json())
```

Comment: Hi, THX for response. Unfortunately thats not exactly what I need. Please note that 'to_json' is not a 'MyClass' function. Its a function of 'Sequential' class from Keras lib. 'MyClass' contains 'Sequential' object as instance variable.

Comment: @sayaki sorry i misread. I'm not familiar with MagicMock. Are you able to move self.model.to_json() into its own method in 'MyClass' something like 'load_model()' and call this method from save()? You could then patch it as I mention in my answer

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a direct way to patch method from Keras object but yours idea is actually great. If I won't find a better way I will use it for sure. THX!

Comment: @Sayaki Were you able to figure out a solution to your problem? It may be beneficial to the community post your answer if you did